# performing an update query with a select subquery returning either the same value for ALL of the records or ora-01427 error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I need to update a column in one table with the results from a select sub-query (and they should ultimately be different).  But When I do this, I either get the exact same number for the hundreds of records, or I get the ORA-01427: single row sub-query returns more than one row query. error.

Can you please take a look and see what it is that I am overlooking? (I could just be overlooking something simple for all I know)

```
UPDATE WD_PRODUCT_CLASS
SET CURRENT_CASES =  (  WITH STUFF_COUNT AS
(
SELECT sum(CURRENT_DETAIL.COMBINED_QTY) AS TOTAL_CASES
    FROM CURRENT_DETAIL, SKU_MAJORS, WD_PRODUCT_CLASS
    WHERE CURRENT_DETAIL.LOC_ID =
      &PARM_LOC_ID
    AND CURRENT_DETAIL.INVEN_ID   = SKU_MAJORS.INVEN_ID
    AND WD_PRODUCT_CLASS.CATEGORY = SKU_MAJORS.CONT_DESC
    GROUP BY WD_PRODUCT_CLASS.CATEGORY 
)
  (
    SELECT SUM(Z.TOTAL_CASES) FROM STUFF_COUNT Z 
 )
);
```

Comment: If you execute the subquery how many rows are returned?

Comment: I receive 8 from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need someting like this:

```
UPDATE WD_PRODUCT_CLASS wpc
SET wpc.CURRENT_CASES = (  
    SELECT sum(cd.COMBINED_QTY)
    FROM CURRENT_DETAIL cd join SKU_MAJORS sm ON cd.INVEN_ID = sm.INVEN_ID 
    WHERE cd.LOC_ID = &PARM_LOC_ID
      AND sm.CONT_DESC = wpc.CATEGORY
        )
WHERE 1=1; -- if you don't set a condition all the rows will be updated
```

Your query updates the table with the same values because you're using a not correlated subquery in the SET clause. This subquery don't depends on the parent query, so it's calculated only once.

I suppose you need a correlated subquery so I changed your update + removed some extra parts.